# MASTER-MASTER replication failed on Production: Coordinator stopped because there were error(s) in the worker(s)

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0, master-master-replication

This error occured after I was importing a database dump to master1.

In production our MASTER-MASTER replication failed

### UPDATE

`SELECT CHANNEL_NAME, WORKER_ID, THREAD_ID, SERVICE_STATE, LAST_ERROR_NUMBER, LAST_ERROR_MESSAGE FROM performance_schema.replication_applier_status_by_worker;`

giving output on **Master1**:

```
Worker 1 failed executing transaction 'ANONYMOUS' at master log node1-bin.000018, end_log_pos 594107878; Error 'Duplicate foreign key constraint name 'client_potential_meganet_agreements_client_id_foreign'' on query. Default database: 'netcore_support'. Query: 'ALTER TABLE `client_potential_meganet_agreements`ADD CONSTRAINT client_potential_meganet_agreements_client_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`client_id`) REFERENCES `client_potential_meganet` (`id`)'
```

giving output on Master2

```
Worker 1 failed executing transaction 'ANONYMOUS' at master log node2-bin.000040, end_log_pos 168239245; Could not execute Write_rows event on table netcore_feedback.sessions; Duplicate entry 'ctthXsIZ32QP8lJsYVInWGZW1GwNNgNN1t1wLGbn' for key 'sessions.PRIMARY', Error_code: 1062; handler error HA_ERR_FOUND_DUPP_KEY; the event's master log FIRST, end_log_pos 168239245
```

**MASTER1 error:**

> Coordinator stopped because there were error(s) in the worker(s). The most recent failure being: Worker 1 failed executing transaction 'ANONYMOUS' at master                           log node1-bin.000018, end_log_pos 594107483. See error log and/or performance_schema.replication_applier_status_by_worker table for more details about this failure or others, if any.

**MASTER2 error:**

> Last_SQL_Error: Coordinator stopped because there were error(s) in the worker(s). The most recent failure being: Worker 1 failed executing transaction 'ANONYMOUS' at master                           log node2-bin.000040, end_log_pos 168239245. See error log and/or performance_schema.replication_applier_status_by_worker table for more details about this failure or others, if any.

**Master1:**

```
SHOW MASTER STATUS;
+------------------+-----------+--------------+------------------+-------------------+
| File             | Position  | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB | Executed_Gtid_Set |
+------------------+-----------+--------------+------------------+-------------------+
| node2-bin.000051 | 434103214 |              |                  |                   |
+------------------+-----------+--------------+------------------+-------------------+
```

**Master2:**

```
show master status;
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+-------------------+
| File             | Position | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB | Executed_Gtid_Set |
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+-------------------+
| node1-bin.000042 |  1451131 |              |                  |                   |
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+-------------------+
```

my configs.

```
[mysqld]

server-id=2
replicate-same-server-id=0
auto-increment-increment=2
auto-increment-offset=2
relay-log=/var/lib/mysql/node2-relay-bin
relay-log-index=/var/lib/mysql/node2-relay-bin.index
log-error=/var/log/mysql/mysql.error
master-info-file=/var/lib/mysql/mysql-master.info
relay-log-info-file=/var/lib/mysql/node1-relay-log.info
log-bin=/var/lib/mysql/node2-bin
max_connections = 1000

datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
log-error=/var/log/mysql/mysqld.log
pid-file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: So, did you "see error log and/or performance_schema.replication_applier_status_by_worker table for more details", as the error message suggests?

Comment: @mustaccio I got this output--

Worker 1 failed executing transaction 'ANONYMOUS' at master log node1-bin.000018, end_log_pos 594107878; Error 'Duplicate foreign key constraint name 'client_potential_meganet_agreements_client_id_foreign'' on query. Default database: 'netcore_support'. Query: 'ALTER TABLE `client_potential_meganet_agreements`
   ADD CONSTRAINT `client_potential_meganet_agreements_client_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`client_id`) REFERENCES `client_potential_meganet` (`id`)'

Comment: @mustaccio I updated my question with full query outputs